# Como puedo mejorar la query en Mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Tengo dos tablas (individuales y grupales) y quiero construir una vista en la que se calculen los totales de tres campos que ambas tienen (condones_entregados, lubricantes_entregados y materiales_educativos_entregados) agrupando los resultados por el id_persona_receptora (que es único). 
En cada una de las tablas, los valores de las columnas (condones_entregados, lubricantes_entregados y materiales_educativos_entregados) tienen valores diferentes.

Asi que la solución que tomé es crear una vista para individual y otra para grupal, donde se calculan la suma de los valores de las tres columnas. Y despues crear una tercera vista donde llevo a cabo la union de ambas.

Alguien que pueda refactorizar ese código? 
Probé en una sola vista con la unión de ambas tablas, pero tuve infinidad de fallos y ésta es la solución que encontré.

Primera Vista

```
SELECT 
    SUM(`condones_entregados`) AS `total_C`,
    SUM(`lubricantes_entregados`) AS `total_L`,
    SUM(`materiales_educativos_entregados`) AS `total_M`,
    `id_persona_receptora`
FROM
    `promotor_realiza_actividad_grupal_con_personas_receptoras`
GROUP BY `id_persona_receptora`
```

Segunda Vista

```
   SELECT 
    SUM(`condones_entregados`) AS `total_C`,
    SUM(`lubricantes_entregados`) AS `total_L`,
    SUM(`materiales_educativos_entregados`) AS `total_M`,
    `id_persona_receptora`
FROM
    `promotor_realiza_entrevista_individual`
GROUP BY `id_persona_receptora`
```

Vista Final

```
 SELECT 
    `i`.`id_persona_receptora` AS `id_persona_receptora`,
    (`i`.`total_C` + `g`.`total_C`) AS `C`,
    (`i`.`total_L` + `g`.`total_L`) AS `L`,
    (`i`.`total_M` + `g`.`total_M`) AS `M`
FROM
    (`total_grupales` `i`
    LEFT JOIN `total_individuales` `g` ON ((`i`.`id_persona_receptora` = `g`.`id_persona_receptora`)))
```

Comment: la persona siempre esta en las dos tablas? o puede estar solo en una?. si solo puede estar en una el LEFT, RIGHT o INNER no funcionaran.

Comment: En tu vista final si la persona está en la tabla g, pero no en la i, debido a que usas un left, ese registro jamas te aparecerá

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que juntes las dos tablas con la sentencia UNION ALL, de esta manera no importará si solo esta en una tabla. La vista te quedaria algo asi:

```
CREATE VIEW entrega_condones AS 
SELECT
g.condones_entregados AS condones_entregados,
g.lubricantes_entregados AS lubricantes_entregados,
g.materiales_educativos_entregados AS materiales_educativos_entregados,
g.id_persona_receptora AS id_persona_receptora 
FROM
    promotor_realiza_actividad_grupal_con_personas_receptoras g 
UNION ALL
SELECT
    i.condones_entregados AS condones_entregados,
    i.lubricantes_entregados AS lubricantes_entregados,
    i.materiales_educativos_entregados AS materiales_educativos_entregados,
    i.id_persona_receptora AS id_persona_receptora 
FROM
    promotor_realiza_entrevista_individual i
```

Una vez unidas las dos tablas, simplemente sacas la suma de los totales:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(condones_entregados) AS total_C,
    SUM(lubricantes_entregados) AS total_L,
    SUM(materiales_educativos_entregados) AS total_M,
    id_persona_receptora
FROM
    entrega_condones
GROUP BY id_persona_receptora
```

Comment: Gracias Manuel Alberto y disculpa por la tardanza de mi respuesta